# Exposing POST Endpoint on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, nginx, cors

I have a Chrome extension that needs to send data to a separate application I have running on Elastic Beanstalk via POST request.  The POST endpoint itself is working fine via http, as confirmed using cURL.

However, given I am posting JSON data from a non-origin domain, the AJAX POST request is performed via https.  This is causing the POST request to timeout, both from the Chrome extension and from cURL.  I've done some research on how to change the CORS settings on the nginx server on Elastic Beanstalk, but I don't *really* know what I'm doing and kinda grasping at straws.  How can I enable CORS on ELB/nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGINX instance working on EB machines are just proxying the request to your application and passing back the response to the client. You can set CORS headers in your application and that's it.

Comment: So I added CORS headers in my express application, but any https request to the app is still timing out.  Perhaps this isn't a CORS problem?  Is there any other way I can test to see what's wrong?

Comment: CORS problem would not cause timeout. You said you can't access via HTTPS even with curl, and curl does not care about CORS. I guess you did not enable HTTPS listener on ELB. Check if your URL is listening port 443.

Comment: I added an HTTPS server, and now it is working locally with curl.  Still need to get it working remotely on AWS.

Comment: You should check documentation on how to enable HTTPS on elastic beanstalk. It seems like the timeout is caused by missing setting. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html